# Transpose and rearrange rows in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have several files with the following structure:

```
data <- matrix(c(1:100000), nrow=1000, ncol=100)
```

The first 500 rows are X coordinates and the final 500 rows are Y coordinates of several object contours. Row # 1 (X) and row 501 (Y) correspond to coordinates of the same object. I need to:

- transpose the whole matrix and arrange it so now row 1 is column 1 and row 501 is column 2 and have paired x, y coordinates in contiguous columns. Row 2 and row 502 should be in column 1 and column 2 below the data of previous object.
- ideally, have an extra column with filename info.

thanks.

Comment: It is always better to show a small example instead of a big dataset so that it becomes easier to test.

Comment: Wouldn't the file name be repeated 50000 times if the matrix is just from one file?  Store the file name in a separate object, or with the matrix in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler version:

Transpose the matrix, then create a vector with the column indices and subset with them:

```
mat <- matrix(1:100, nrow = 10)
mat2 <- t(mat)
cols <- unlist(lapply(1:(nrow(mat2)/2), function(i) c(i, i+nrow(mat2)/2)))
mat3 <- mat2[,cols]
```

Then just make it a dataframe as below.

---

You can subset pairs of rows separated by `nrow`/2, make them a 2-column matrix and then `cbind` them all:

```
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(1:(nrow(mat)/2), function(i) {
  matrix(mat[c(i, nrow(mat)/2 + i),], ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
})))
df
# V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 fname
# 1   1  6  2  7  3  8  4  9  5  10     a
# 2  11 16 12 17 13 18 14 19 15  20     e
# 3  21 26 22 27 23 28 24 29 25  30     e
# 4  31 36 32 37 33 38 34 39 35  40     o
# 5  41 46 42 47 43 48 44 49 45  50     y
# 6  51 56 52 57 53 58 54 59 55  60     q
# 7  61 66 62 67 63 68 64 69 65  70     v
# 8  71 76 72 77 73 78 74 79 75  80     b
# 9  81 86 82 87 83 88 84 89 85  90     v
# 10 91 96 92 97 93 98 94 99 95 100     y
```

Then just add the new column as necessary, since it's now a dataframe:

```
df$fname <- sample(letters, nrow(df), TRUE)
```

Comment: Don't forget to move `mat <- matrix(1:100, nrow = 10)` at the top of your post, or your added code will fail.

Answer (score -1):

What about

```
n <- 500
df <- data.frame(col1 = data[1:n, ],
                 col2 = data[(nrow(data) - 500):nrow(data), ],
                 fileinfo = "this is the name of the file...")
```

Comment: How about testing your solution before posting?

Answer (score -1):

Try David's answer, but this way:

```
n <- 500
df <- data.frame(col1 = data[1:n, ],
                 col2 = data[(nrow(data) - (n-1)):nrow(data), ],
                 fileinfo = "this is the name of the file...")
```